# Replay Kafka topic from the last successful message

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

With the standard configuration of a channel on Spring Cloud Stream a message is retried 3 times and then skipped. If the following message processing completes successfully the offset is committed.
That means that under transient exceptions messages can be lost.

Can this behavior be changed, so the channel get stuck on a failing message until the transient condition is repaired?

I have tried configuring the retry template, but you have to specify a number of retries, which looks like a useless parameter, as the desired behavior is retrying forever.

Did anyone fall into these troubles? Thank you.

I also have some doubts about how this can interfere with the `max.poll.interval.ms` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable retry in the binder and use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` to add a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with infinite retries...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63193500Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63193500Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<String> input() {
        return str -> {
            System.out.println(str);
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer() {
        return (container, dest, group) -> {
            if (group.equals("so63193500")) {
                container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                        new FixedBackOff(5_000, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=so63193500
```

This causes a seek and won't affect the poll interval as long as the back off interval is not too long.

You can also use an `ExponentialBackOff`.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, is this unlimited attemps a good practice?, what if the problem was caused by a "poison pill", will the consumer get stuck? Or FixedBackOff help with that?, thanks in advance

Comment: I would say no, it's not good practice; the framework provides a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to send the failed record to another topic and move on to the next (after some number of retries). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters

Comment: Starting with version 2.6.0, you can select the `BackOff` to use based on the exception type, so you can select infinite retries if you know it's a transient problem.