# How to do message filtering at Kafka record level when using SpringCloudStream?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream (SCS) with Kafka as a binder.

I would like to do low-level filtering on records based on the Kafka header. What would be the recommended approach?

The filtered message should be ignored and the offset should be committed.

I was thinking about configuring a RecordFilterStrategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RecordFilterStrategy` is not supported by Spring Cloud Stream.

You can add `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193500/replay-kafka-topic-from-the-last-successful-message/63194089#63194089) and add a `RecordInterceptor` to the listener container. If the interceptor returns null, the listener is not called and the offset will be committed, as if the listener was called and exited normally.

Comment: Thx a lot that's what I have figured out in the meantime :).

Is there even lower-level way of implementing it? I would like the minimum impacts possible on performances.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The interceptor should add very little overhead.

Comment: @GaryRussell - which API of the AbstractMessageListenerContainer do we use to set the RecordInterceptor ? I am at my wits end to figure this out. Any help or hint will ease my life :-)

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/e9b5e69afb4657b1b32d1e803fb622a25669bdd5/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java#L409-L417

Comment: @GaryRussell - thanks :-) . somehow Google search kept referring me to `org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer` . Now its clear.